# CSS display:inline property with list-style-image: property on <li> tags

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem using CSS's `display:inline` property with the `list-style-image:` property on `<li>` tags. Basically, I want to output the following:

```
* Link 1  * Link 2
```

where `*` represents an image.

I'm doing this with the following bit of HTML:

```
<ol class="widgets">
    <li class="l1">Link 1</li>
    <li class="l2">Link 2</li>
</ol>
```

which is styled with the following bit of CSS:

```
ol.widgets { list-style-type:none; }

ol.widgets li { display:inline;
                margin-left:10px; }

ol.widgets li.l1 { list-style-image:url(image1.gif); }

ol.widgets li.l2 { list-style-image:url(image2.gif); }
```

The problem is that when the list items are displayed inline, the images associated with the list items do not appear. They *do* appear if I take out the `display:inline` property on the `<li>` tag.

Is there a way to make the images appear even when the list items are displayed inline, or is that just impossible?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try using `float: left` (or `right`) instead of `display: inline`. Inline display replaces list-item display, which is what adds the bullet points.

Comment: Great! It still didn't look quite right (the images overlapped some text), but adding list-style-position:inside to all <li> elements did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: something else is wrong then, this *is* the correct technique. try appropriate margins on the <li>'s and failing that try it in a simple test page

Comment: I used display: inline with :before for the bullets. Works great! I prefer this as an alternative for floats

Answer (score 6):

You want the list items to line up next to each other, but not really be inline elements. So float them instead:

```
ol.widgets li { 
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem, i solve using css ":before".. the code looks likes this:

```
.widgets li:before{
    content:"• ";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [the 'display' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop) in the CSS spec, you will see that 'list-item' is specifically a display type. When you set an item to "inline", you're replacing the default display type of list-item, and [the marker is specifically a part of the list-item type](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#lists).

The above answer suggests float, but I've tried that and it doesn't work (at least on Chrome). [According to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position), if you set your boxes to float left or right,"The 'display' is ignored, unless it has the value 'none'." I take this to mean that the default display type of 'list-item' is gone (taking the marker with it) as soon as you float the element.

Edit: Yeah, I guess I was wrong. See top entry. :)

Answer (score 2):

You want style image and Nav with float to each other then use like this

```
ol.widgets ul
{
list-style-image:url('some-img.gif');
}
ol.widgets ul li
{
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to use `list-style-image`, as it behaves quite differently in different browsers, especially the image position

instead, you can use something like this

```
ol.widgets,
ol.widgets li { list-style: none; }
ol.widgets li { padding-left: 20px; backgroud: transparent ("image") no-repeat x y; }
```

it works in all browsers and would give you the identical result in different browsers.

Comment: I actually think this is probably the right tack to take on the bullet images, but they should still be floated not inlined

Comment: yep, inline sometimes causes list-style-position problems, it's frustrating in IE.